# Can wsdl2java generated files be used in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, wsdl

Java files generated by [wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) require javax.xml.bind.*, javax.xml.ws.*, etc. that Android does not seem to support.

Is there a way to remedy this?